# numpy array slicing index

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

- How can I get zeroth index column? Expecting output `[[1],[2],[3]]` `a[...,0]` gives 1D array. Maybe next question answers this question.
- How to get last 2 columns of `a`? `a[...,1:2]` gives second column only, `a[...,2:3]` gives last 2 columns, but `a[...,3]` is invalid dimension. So, how does it work?

By the way, operator `...` and `:` have same meaning? `a[...,0]` and `a[:,0]` give same output. Can someone comment here?

Comment: It's no zero-th index column, but transposed first row. Try: ```a[:,0].T``` to get there. NB ```print(a)``` to see what's column, what's row

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski, `a[:,0]` is 1d, so `.T` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` indexing is built on `python` list conventions, but extended to multi-dimensions and multi-element indexing.  It is powerful, but complex, but sooner or later you should read a full `indexing` documentation, one that distinguishes between 'basic' and 'advanced' indexing.

Like `range` and `arange`, slice index has a 'open' stop value

```
In [111]: a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)                                                       
In [112]: a                                                                                      
Out[112]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Indexing with a scalar reduces the dimension, regardless of where:

```
In [113]: a[1,:]                                                                                 
Out[113]: array([4, 5, 6])
In [114]: a[:,1]                                                                                 
Out[114]: array([2, 5, 8])
```

That also means `a[1,1]` returns `5`, not `np.array([[5]])`.

Indexing with a slice preserves the dimension:

```
In [115]: a[1:2,:]                                                                               
Out[115]: array([[4, 5, 6]])
```

so does indexing with a list or array (though this makes a `copy`, not a `view`):

```
In [116]: a[[1],:]                                                                               
Out[116]: array([[4, 5, 6]])
```

`...` is a generalized `:` - use as many as needed.

```
In [117]: a[...,[1]]                                                                             
Out[117]: 
array([[2],
       [5],
       [8]])
```

You can adjust dimensions with `newaxis` or reshape:

```
In [118]: a[:,1,np.newaxis]                                                                      
Out[118]: 
array([[2],
       [5],
       [8]])
```

Note that trailing `:` are automatic.  `a[1]` is the same as `a[1,:]`.  But leading ones must be explicit.

List indexing also removes a 'dimension/nesting layer'

```
In [119]: alist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]                                                              
In [120]: alist[0]                                                                               
Out[120]: [1, 2, 3]
In [121]: alist[0][0]                                                                            
Out[121]: 1
In [122]: [l[0] for l in alist]     # a column equivalent                                                                  
Out[122]: [1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

a[:,0] # first colomn
>>> array([1, 4, 7]) 
a[0,:] # first row
>>> array([1, 2, 3])
a[:,0:2] # first two columns
>>> array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
a[0:2,:] # first two rows
>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: `a[:,0] # first colomn` doesn't column start with zero-index (as in cpython objects)?